# Material UI filled input for KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: material-ui

I know that with an InputField one is able to pass down the `variant="filled"` prop to get input box filled. However, is it also possible to pass down a prop with the similar effect using a Material UI date picker (not using the native datepicker from the browser)?

Example of filled input:

[image]

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `inputVariant={"filled"}` prop

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = date => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          inputVariant={"filled"}
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Working [sandbox project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fctm2?file=/demo.js:0-1066)

Answer (score 0):

#### The @material-ui/pickers has been moved to the @mui/lab.

> Checkout the migration guide [Here](https://mui.com/guides/pickers-migration/) !

Below is a sample code to implement the same

```
import React from "react";
import TextField  from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";

export default function filledDatePicker() {

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleDateChange = date => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
       <DatePicker
         value={selectedDate}
         onChange={handleDateChange}
         renderInput={(props) => (
          <TextField {...props} variant="filled" label="Select Date" />
           )}
       />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );

}
```